# How to build electron GUI for CLI tool with electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I've made an electron app which is an GUI for 3rd party CLI tool and luckily it works fine in development mode when I run `electron .`

In main process my app runs script `s3-download-client/bin/s3-download-client` with node's `child_process.spawn()` and it works ok, because I know the path to the CLI tool. It's defined in `src/main/index.js` as:

```
const DOWNLOAD_CLIENT = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 's3-download-client/bin/s3-download-client');
```

However, I have no idea how to configure `electron-builder` to include that external tool in my built app and make it work together.

Here is my project structure:

```
.
├── package.json
├── s3-download-client
│   ├── bin
│   │   └── s3-download-client
└── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   └── someLib.js
│   └── renderer
│       ├── app.js
│       ├── controllers
│       ├── index.html
│       └── templates
```

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "logs-explorer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/main/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "your.id",
    "mac": {
      "category": "your.app.category.type"
    }
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.8",
    "angular-eonasdan-datetimepicker": "^0.3.9",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.8",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.47",
    "jquery": "^3.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "opn": "^5.2.0",
    "tempy": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.10",
    "electron-builder": "^19.54.0"
  }
}
```

I suppose I may have to define path to the CLI tool in my code in another way, and add some additional `electron-builder's` configuration in `package.json` but I cannot find how should it look like.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was simply. I had to define `files` property with paths to resources that I want to include in the built app. I didn't have to change any paths in my app code. Unfortunately I had to use `asar: false` flag, because with default `true` value my app didn't work. Probably it can be fixed with `asarUnpack` property somehow, but I didn't succeed with it.

Here is the `electron-builder` config from my `package.json`:

```
  "build": {
    "appId": "your.id",
    "mac": {
      "category": "your.app.category.type"
    },
    "files": [
      "s3-download-client/**/*",
      "src/**/*"
    ],
    "asar": false
  }
```

Including `node_modules` in `files` is not required, but of course you have to specify all other directories.